# HTML resources not loading when using custom 400 error page for Nginx specifically for SSL

Tags: html, nginx, nginx-config

I added my custom designed pages to my `Nginx` config file and they all work great in other scenarios. The only case that my custom error page is shown but resources does not get loaded is when user tries to access an address which is SSL with typing http in the URL. For example instead of `https://192.168.1.1:789`, `http://192.168.1.1:789` is typed which throws `400` error page without resources being loaded properly(for example images). I assume it is because for example it tries to get `src="../error_pages/assets/images/img12.png"` from `http://192.168.1.1:789/error_pages/assets/images/img12.png"` which is not available! Can you please tell me how should I approach this problem?
my `Nginx` config file:

```
upstream dashboardapp{
    
        server test_server:80;
}
server {
    listen 789 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/host.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/host.key;

    location / {

        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800;
        send_timeout 1800;
        proxy_hide_header x_destination;
        proxy_pass http://dashboardapp;

    }
    location /error_pages {
                root /etc/nginx/;
        }
    error_page 495 496 497 /400_page.html;
        location = /400_page.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
                internal;
        }
    error_page 404 /404_page.html;
        location = /404_page.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
                internal;
        }
    
    error_page 500 /500_page.html;
        location = /500_page.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
                internal;
        }
    error_page 502 /502_page.html;
        location = /502_page.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
                internal;
        }
    error_page 503 /503_page.html;
        location = /503_page.html {
                root /etc/nginx/error_pages;
                internal;
        }
}
```

Sample error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Oops! Page not found</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../error_pages/assets/images/cropped.png" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Google font -->
    <link href="../error_pages/assets/CSS/google.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../error_pages/assets/CSS/googlefont2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }

        #notfound {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        }

        #notfound .notfound {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .notfound {
        max-width: 520px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.4;
        text-align: center;
        }

        .notfound .notfound-404 {
        position: relative;
        height: 240px;
        }

        .notfound .notfound-404 h1 {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size: 252px;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #C94110;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: -40px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        }

        .notfound .notfound-404 h1>span {
        text-shadow: -8px 0px 0px #fff;
        }

        .notfound .notfound-404 h3 {
        font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #262626;
        margin: 0px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        padding-left: 6px;
        }

        .notfound h2 {
        font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #000;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .notfound .notfound-404 {
            height: 200px;
        }
        .notfound .notfound-404 h1 {
            font-size: 200px;
        }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .notfound .notfound-404 {
            height: 162px;
        }
        .notfound .notfound-404 h1 {
            font-size: 162px;
            height: 150px;
            line-height: 162px;
        }
        .notfound h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        }
        .button {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #C94110;
        border: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 5px;
        }

        .button span {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .button span:after {
        content: '\00bb';
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: -20px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .button:hover span {
        padding-right: 25px;
        }

        .button:hover span:after {
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
        }
                
    </style>


</head>

<body background="../error_pages/assets/images/background.jpg">
    <div id="notfound">
        <div class="notfound">
            <img src="../error_pages/assets/images/img12.png" width="400" height="157">
            <p></p>
            <div class="notfound-404">
                <h3>Oops! Page not found</h3>
                <h1><span>4</span><span>0</span><span>0</span></h1>
            </div>
            <h3>The page you are looking for might have been removed had its name changed or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
            <a id="myElementID" href="#" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Home Page</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById('myElementID');
    a.href = "http://"+window.location.hostname;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx looks for the first matching server for the request based on port, protocol (e.g. http vs https) and [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).  If there is no `default_server` then it will take the first one that matches the best or possibly return `400` for bad request if it can't find any matching server blocks.  See [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more details on how server block matching works.

When you request http (NOT https) on port `789`, that does NOT match your server block because the request is http and not https.

Normally in port 80/443 case you would probably match the default server config that was installed with your nginx package.  But as you are running on a special port, it is likely nginx is returning a 400 because it cannot find any server block that handles http on port `789`.

I suggest you configure a [`default_server`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for nginx to handle BOTH http and https.  This can be used to serve error pages for any requests that come in on hostnames you don't want to allow (or whatever else you want to do).  It ensures you have control over config of all request handling coming into the server.  Note that http and https should be on different ports.

Okay, it is technically possible to handle both http and https on same port in nginx if you really must.  You may also find this [question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a solution for you to redirect http requests to https? (Which is actually common)

Your config file should get another server block:

```
# force https
server {
  listen 789;
  server_name  example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 789 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/host.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/host.key;

    location / {
...
```